# In The Sims 4 i’m trying to detail edit them but the icon isn’t there on the left side of their head

Tags: the-sims-4

I’ve tried to detail edit every single sim and the icon just isn’t there, is this because they’re already existing and i can only do this on new sims or can i do something to get that icon back?

Comment: Have you entered the character creator via the debug menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can only initially carry out detailed edits on Sims that are newly created. However, you can do the following to edit them later on:

- Press Ctrl + Shift + C to bring up the cheat console.
- Enter testingcheats true.
- Enter cas.fulleditmode (this enables you to make full edits, like when you start a new game)
- Now click on a sim while holding Shift down. You should get an "Edit in CAS" option.
  Click that option and you're ready to edit your sim.

Answer (score -1):

You can also get there by clicking a mirror in your household , there should be an option to ‘change sim’.
i seen on another post that you can enter cas edit mode like this : CAS.fulleditmode
i haven’t tried it, clicking the mirror and choosing ‘change sim’ worked for me :)

Comment: The problem the OP is pointing out is that they can't, because the icon isn't there. Your other solution is already mentioned in the other answer (maybe you saw that post on this same page?).

Comment: well idk what to tell you then fr lol

Comment: and na i saw it on a post from 7 years ago bc i was having the same problems, then i seen the mirror option n tried it n it works so i thought i could help someone else out, but you’re snobby and want everything a certain way so excuse my comment  sorry for helping u